# How to pass the variables from one ksh script to another ksh script in Linux

Tags: linux, ksh

I have below 2 scripts

`Script1.ksh`

```
      Some  Code

      Var1 = value1

      Var2 = value2

      Var3 = value3
```

`Script2.ksh`

```
     Ksh path/Script1.ksh

     #Trying to use Var1, Var2, Var3 in below code.
     
      Some Code
```

I want to use these `Var1,Var2,Var3` values in `Script2.ksh`. I searched the web and tried export option and it didn’t work out. Please help me in this issue.

Comment: an easy method is from script1 to write a local `myapplication.env` to set the variables  file & read it in script 2 `source .myapplication.env`

Comment: `Var1`, `Var2`, and `Var3` are local variables in Script1.ksh.  When the process running that script terminates, those variables no longer exist. `export` makes the variables available in the environment of subprocesses of Script1.ksh, but that is not relevant, so export cannot help you. You need some form of IPC.

Comment: I'd advise you to check how to set environment variables.

Comment: My favorite way to do such things is ```env -i VARNAME1='Value1' VARNAME2='Value2' scripname.sh``` from the script. No need to use ```export VARNAME1='Value1'```. I often use it for the X DISPLAY variable for example.

Answer (score 0):

In script2, when you do

```
ksh path/to/script1.ksh
```

that launches a new ksh process, executes the script (setting the variables) and then the process exits, taking the variables with it.

You need to use the `.` command (or its alias `source`) to read script1 *in the current process*.

```
source path/to/script1.ksh
```